# detect if circle is completed using location

Tags: java, android, algorithm, math

Is there any way by which I can programmatically know if a circle is completed?

First, the user will click start and then the current location is retrieved and saved.

After that, I need to get notified once the circle is completed not necessarily on the exact location, check attached image.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying the circle is completed as long as it ends up on the same radius as it started?  If that's the case, then you probably just want to compute the angle and see if the angle is the same.  The solution will probably involve `Math.atan2(y-y0,x-x0)` where `x0` and `y0` are the coordinates of the center.

Comment: I have the coordinates of the starting point but I don't have the coordinates of the center.

Comment: It's not very specific. If you put the center lower than where it is on your figure, the circle was completed much earlier.

Comment: More or less no because almost any movement that returns closer to the origin would fit into some circle somehow. And if your circles are small you'll get even funnier results because location inaccuracy may move the user in a circle without him actually moving.

Comment: It might still be possible.  If you can figure out the angle at which the point moves when the circle is started, and then figure out when the angle at which the point is moving becomes the starting angle again, you could then imagine a perpendicular at the ending point and determine whether it intersects the curve in some other place, presumably closer to the starting point.  That's all pretty fuzzy, though.

Comment: On thinking a bit more: once you figure out the starting point and starting angle, you can create an imaginary perpendicular line that runs through that point, and consider the circle completed when they cross that line going in approximately the same direction.

Answer (score 0):

Take the pairwise differences of point coordinates as an approximation for tangent direction.

I'd consider splitting the full circle into four quadrants, delimited by the following directions: the first tangent direction (between the first pair of points) as well as the directions 90°, 180° and 270° rotated against that. A proper smooth circle would pass through each of these segments in order: first directions would be between 0° and 90° (again with the initial direction as reference), then between 90° and 180°, then between 180° and 270°, and then between 270° and 360°=0°. Once it comes back into the first of these quadrants, you know that you have  completed the turn.

You could do the same with two instead of four sectors, but four is more robust: a little jitter in tangent direction may make you switch between two adjacent segments several times, but never across more than two. So with four segments, you can allow for some going back and forth and still detect when the circle is completed.

Comment: can you elaborate more? or give a simple technical example if possible